# jQuery Print elements pushed into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, append

I have the following code:

```
var $element1 = $('#selector'),
    $element2...;

var $elements = [ $element1, $element2, $element3 ],
    $classes = ['class1','class2','class3'],
    $newElements = [];

$.each($elements, function($i, $element){
    $newElements.push('<li class="'+ $classes[$i]+'">' + $element +'</li>');
});

$(body).append( $newElements );
```

The output being:

```
<li class="class1">[object Object]</li>
<li class="class2">[object Object]</li>
<li class="class3">[object Object]</li>
```

How can I print the actual elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual elements data"? The text within those elements? Are they inputs, and you want their values? Do they have `.data()` attributes that you want to use? Can you should us some of the elements, and the output you'd *like* to see from those elements?

Comment: I meant the elements as string, not elements data. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `outerHTML` of the element being appended:

```
$.each($elements, function($i, $element){
    $newElements.push('<li class="'+ $classes[$i]+'">' + $element[0].outerHTML +'</li>');
});
```